# How to Represent Data in Django with Django Querysets

Tags: python, django

Model Data Format:

[image: Model Data Format]

I have a Django Model which have data similar to the above image data Structure.

Now I want to represent the Data in my HTML Template according to the Following Structure.

Date & Labour Wise Data Representation:

[image: Date & Labour Wise Data Representation]

and Labour Wise Data Representation:

[image: Labour Wise Data Representation]

Note - in the 3rd Image "Labour Wise data Representation"..There are certain additional fields added like "Per day Salary" & some Calculation of Salary, Net Salary, EPF & ESIC etc.

Any Help, How can I get this Done in Django?

Comment: We don't see this site as a code writing service. What have you tried so far? Where are having problems?

Comment: I Just planed it out...But unable to figure out the way to start...I can iterate through for loop but here I'll have to combine the data Labour wise in the 2nd Example..& for the 1st Example..I can iterate the date in 1st column & labors in the 1st row however could not figure out the way to iterate the Shift & overtime in relation with Date & Labour Name.

Comment: I don't want Code, I just want some suggestions to start.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Way Out...Using the Annotate

atd_rep = Attendance.objects.values('labour__name').annotate(shift_count=Sum(
        'shift_count'), overtime_count=Sum('overtime_count'), off_count=Sum('off_count'))